# Can I associate my account to two gmail addresses?

Tags: support

I just changed jobs and so I got a new email account. Both are through Gmail. I prefer to keep them separate rather than trying to merge them. When I log in to MathOverflow I always verify using Google. Now I'm having the problem that if I try to log in from a browser which has my new email address open then MathOverflow doesn't recognize me. Is it possible to associate the new email address to the existing MathOverflow account?

Comment: Yes, you can. Go to your profile page, click on `my logins` and then on `add more logins... ` and select Google.

Comment: Great, thanks! Works perfectly